# Find button in a EXT JS form

Tags: forms, extjs

I can do `myForm.getForm().findField('myFld');` to find a field by name. What's the equivalent of finding a button?

Comment: finding a button is also same, if you have a name for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields exept name can also have ref propety:

```
name: 'fieldID',
ref: 'your_reference',
```

this way you do not need to find them - to access `this.your_reference`

you can do it with button also. Trick is: if button is on toolbar (top or bottom) use `ref: '../your_btn_ref'` to get 1 level up 9direct will go to toolbar)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [`find`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Container.html#method-Ext.Container-find)? "Find a component under this container at any level by property."

More generally, you can use `findBy`.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?67059-how-to-find-a-Button-by-its-id):

```
getItemByItemId(btnId)
```

Answer (score 1):

using "ref" doesnt always work, it is abit hit and miss.

I would recommend either giving the button and ID and using Ext.getCmp(buttonid);

or

Search for the button class using Ext.select and select the approriate array key, Ext.select();